# How to correctly use environment variables in a Next.js application with Firebase and avoid Firebase app duplication errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

How can I initialize Firebase with environmental variables in Next.js without encountering a FirebaseError: "Firebase App named '[DEFAULT]' already exists with different options or config (app/duplicate-app)" when I try to use .env.local file variables in my code to define the Firebase configuration, as shown in the example below?

```
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.APIKEY,
  authDomain: process.env.AUTHDOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.PROJECTID,
  storageBucket: process.env.STORAGEBUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.MESSAGINGSENDERID,
  appId: process.env.APPID
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

note i am using nextjs with jsx javascript not typescript and tailwindcss with firebase/firestore for the backend

Answer (score 1):

I'm a ReactJS developer and do not have any experience in NextJS. However, from the firebase error, it seems you are trying to initialize firebase multiple times or in multiple modules.

How I tackled this error (and hopefully it works for you), is by having a Firebase.js file seperate from other components, and doing my initialization and configuration in here, then any resource I need would be exported and then imported from the file where it is needed. For example in a project where I would need to use storage functions, I would do this

Firebase.js:

```
// imports
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getStorage } from "firebase/storage";

// initialize
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
  measurementId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID,
};
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// exports
export const storage = getStorage(app);
```

and then I can get this from any component as so

Component.js:

```
import { storage } from "./Firebase"; // or whatever the path to the Firebase.js file is in your case
```

Hence I can do all my firebase initializing once.
Hopefully it works for NextJS :)